# iOS simulator for El Capitan

Tags: iphone, macos, safari, development, xcode-simulator

I am a web developer and I often need to do testing on *`i`* devices. I have a macbook around and I don't know what is the best way to test my web applications on iOS devices. I don't have any physical iPhones or iPads (*yet*).

Is there any simple & good iOS simulator? I'm interested to debug the JavaScript in Safari, in developer tools.

Is it possible to install the simulator without installing XCode?

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Xcode, there's not really any way to get an iOS simulator that I know of. Alternatively, you could download Xcode and just pull the iOS simulator out of it from the path `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`.

*edit: to run Safari in Debug mode on your virtual iPhone, there are a set of instructions on [tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787). In essence:*

- *open iOS Simulator*
- *from the menubar, `Develop > iPhone Simulator > (website name)*
- *this should open a side window with Safari Developer Tools*

Comment: Where is the `Xcode.app` directory located?

Comment: Usually in `/Applications`. You'll have to download the application first to extract the Simulator app.

Comment: That's correct. The full path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator`. But how can I open the developer tools in Safari from iPhone?

Comment: I believe I have misunderstood that you were looking for an iOS simulator that runs Safari. I would think you are looking for Safari's developer tools on an iPhone simulator on a Mac?

Comment: First thing is to get the simulator working (I did that by installing XCode and running the `Simulator` executable in the terminal), but I'd like to debug Safari in the iPhone simulator, without having a physical device. Is it even possible?

Comment: It seems to be. I'd advise taking a look at [this article on tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787). I'll add this to my answer when I get back.